# Google Finance Lock Out - Robot

Tags: python, captcha, bots, google-finance

So I have run into the issue of getting data from Google Finance. They have an html access system that you can use to access webpages that give stock data in simple text format (ideal for minimizing parsing). However, if you access this service too frequently, Google locks you out and you need to enter a captcha. I currently have a list of about 50 stocks and I want to update my price data every 15 seconds, but I soon get locked out (after about 3-4 minutes).

Does anyone have any solutions to this/understand the nature of how often is the max I could ping Google for this information?

Not sure why a feature like this would be on a service designed to give data like this... but similar alternative services with realtime data would also be accepted.

Comment: Do you mean this: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/

Comment: No not exactly, as far as I knew google finance removed their official api, I am using the html pages that follow: http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=%s:%sEXCHANGE:STOCKTICKER

Comment: Please note this is written in Python

Comment: 200 requests per minute is pretty high (almost 300,000 per day). Good luck finding a free service that will allow you to do this.

Comment: This is a customer service-related question. Address your issues and complaints about Google's services with their customer service department. This site is for specific questions related to programming (code) or use of a programmer's tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo YQL works fairly well, but throws numerous HTTP 500 errors that need to be handled, they are all benign. TradeKing is an option, however, the oauth2 package is required and that is very difficult to install properly

Answer (score 0):

Probably because your usage is not what they intended. Every 40x every 15 seconds seems a bit excessive. They had an API that got discontinued some years ago, and there's another SO question with some [available alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040954/alternative-to-google-finance-api) which is probably also a bit out of date.

From google, there is also it's [Finance](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/?csw=1) service with [getStockInfo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/finance/finance-app#getStockInfo%28String%29) which allows to query its database but read their warnings.